# Android's FloatingActionButton has a rendering exception

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Exception raised during rendering:

```
Color value '?attr/colorAccent' must start with # (2 similar errors not shown)
```

What does this mean? The documentation isn't very good on the support library. Does anybody have a good example of how to implement the FloatingActionButton?

Answer (score 1):

please try selecting  the color for your Fab in this way:

```
fab:button_color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
```

Take a look for my full implementation.

```
<com.software.shell.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/sub_category_fab"
    fab:type="DEFAULT"
    android:visibility="visible"
    fab:button_color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    fab:image="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp"
    fab:image_size="@dimen/fab_image_size"
    fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_right"
    fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is looking for a HEX code for the color (e.g. `#FF0000`).
The value `?attr/colorAccent` may be returning `null`.

Try substituting an actual color (HEX-code) for the value.

Comment: Where does ?attr live? I'm trying to look for that folder in the values directory of the Android project and it doesn't exist. Should I be making a folder?

Comment: It is a native default Android file. It will be in the SDK files.
https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.R.attr.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing colors to your AppBaseTheme and error will disappear:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_accent_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_ch_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a bug in design library. I have the same exception raised during rendering (in designer view) but at runtime the floating button works. Moreover, `app:fab_colorNormal` and other fab related attribute are not considered in preview, and there is also a weird square shadow around the button.

All of these is not consinstent with real execution: when I test on both real/emulated device, the button behaves as expected